# Tree structure indicated by spaces

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I am trying to load a csv file into a pandas dataframe which structured in the following way.

```
account,value 
level 1,100
  sub_level 1,80
    sub_sub_level 1,60
    sub_sub_level 2,20
  sub_level 2,20
    sub_sub_level 3,10
    sub_sub_level 4,10
```

Is there any way to parse the data in such a way that I get a pandas dataframe which does reflect the tree structure in this data? So that I get the following structure:

```
account_lvl1,account_lvl2, account_lvl3,value
level 1, sub_level 1, sub_sub_level1, 60
level 1, sub_level 1, sub_sub_level2, 20
level 1, sub_level 2, sub_sub_level3, 10
level 1, sub_level 2, sub_sub_level4, 10
```

Comment: What do you imagine the output would look like? I'm having trouble visualizing how a data frame is your optimal data structure here.

Comment: i have update the question with the desired output